# Simple Adobe Flash game about objects comparison

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

- layout on the game

I'm working on a simple food game where there are 9 pictures of ingredients and every dish has only two of these ingredients found in them. I can specify or hard code which pictures are correct. I dont need to shuffle them too.

The user when successfully clicked on the 2 correct ingredients, an output will be shown below to tell them they have got it correct. If its one or none, the game will reset.

- The problem

I have done the shell so far where the layout of the game has been done but lacking the actionscript portion of the game, i have done some research on memory games but i feel that there is much difference in the coding.

Picture below:

1) The user will start by clicking any 2 square on the left (eg: sp1 and sp3)

2) If it is correct, the user will be brought to another frame to start on the second dish

3) If the combination is wrong, the blue box will show "incorrect" and game resets

[image]

Edited: Added link to fla - Thanks user batman
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/9oz9uikfbyp3rhi/thespicegame.fla?dl=0

Edited: I have been suggested using switch, will try to work on that

```
Edited:
     function checkPicture(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
    if(e.currentTarget == sp1){
        if(e.currentTarget == sp2){
            trace("working");
        }else{          
            trace("notworking");        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current code (or a provide a link to your .fla),  not just a screenshot.  Also, share what you've tried so far - this gives people a better idea of where you're at with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this task.  To summarize what you need to do (regardless of the implementation):

1. You need to associate the two correct spices that go with each dish
2. You need to store in memory the two items that get clicked
3. After the second item is clicked, you need to compare to the two items in memory with whatever mechanism you use to associate the correct spices with current dish.

Since it would appear you are a student and just learning, I'll tailor my solution to your current frame and library based game - keeping in mind the best solution would involve much more programming using class files and no timeline code.

1. Associate your correct spices with a dish. The easiest way to do this, is create a dictionary using the dish buttons as the key. Put this (and all subsequent code unless noted) on your **first** game frame (frame 4 currently).

   ```
   //create a dictionary to store all the correct spices
   var correctSpices:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
   correctSpices[meeBtn2] = [sp1, sp3]; //assign an array containing the correct spices
   correctSpices[chickBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
   correctSpices[satayBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
   correctSpices[laskaBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
   correctSpices[rojakBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
   ```
2. Create a variable to hold the first ingredient that was clicked. Also create a variable that stores the current dish:

   ```
   var firstSpice; //to hold the first spice clicked

   var currentDish; //to hold the current dish
   ```
3. Populate the current dish on whatever frame is for that dish:

   ```
   currentDish = chickBtn2; //put this on the frame where chicken is the dish
   ```
4. You need to populate the first click spice variable when a spice is clicked.  I don't see any click listeners on your spice buttons, so let's assume you have the following:

   ```
   sp1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spiceClick, false,0,true);
   sp2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spiceClick, false, 0, true);
   //...etc with all spices
   ```

   Or the shorthanded sloppy way to do all 9 in 3 lines:

   ```
   for(var i:int=1; i<= 9;i++){
       this["sp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spiceClick, false, 0, true);
   }
   ```

   Then in the click handler:

   ```
   function spiceClick(e:Event):void {

       //If the firstSpice variable is null (empty), assign it the click events current target (which is the item you attached the listener to)
       if(firstSpice == null){
           firstSpice = e.currentTarget;
           firstSpice.mouseEnabled = false; //make it so you can't click this one anymore
           return; //exit this function since we want to wait for the second item to be clicked
       }

       //the second item was clicked if we made it this far, check the results

       if(correctSpices[currentDish].indexOf(firstSpice) > -1){
           //first one was correct, now check the one just clicked
           if(correctSpices[currentDish].indexOf(e.currentTarget) > -1){
               //second one was correct
               nextLevel();
           }else{
               //second one was wrong
           }
       }else{
           //first one was wrong
       }
   }

   function nextLevel(){
       //reset all the mouse enabled properties so you can click all the buttons again
       for(var i:int=1; i<= 9;i++){
           this["sp" + i].mouseEnabled = true;
       }

       //clear the firstSpice var
       firstSpice = null;

       nextFrame(); //goto the next frame
   }
   ```

> Keep in mind, this code will persist for all future frames. As long you have no keyframes or empty frames on your buttons, the mouse listeners and everything will stay the same for all subsequent frames

To that end, I would recommend just adding another layer for the current dish text, and then just hide or disable the dish button when you need to (that way you only attach the mouse listener once).

So on every game frame, you'd have this code:

```
if(currentDish) currentDish.visible = true; //if there was previously a hidden dish button, make it visible again
currentDish = chickBtn2; //assign whatever the current dish btn is for each frame
currentDish.visible = false; //hide the current dish button so it can't be clicked
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code I used for testing: (all on frame 4)

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;


meeBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dishBtnClick);
chickBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dishBtnClick);
satayBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dishBtnClick);
laskaBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dishBtnClick);
rojakBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dishBtnClick);

function dishBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(event.currentTarget){
        case meeBtn2:
            gotoAndStop(4);
            break;

        case chickBtn2:
            gotoAndStop(5);
            break;

        case satayBtn2:
            gotoAndStop(6);
            break;

        case laskaBtn2:
            gotoAndStop(7);
            break;

        case rojakBtn2:
            gotoAndStop(8);
            break;
    }
}



//create a dictionary to store all the correct spices
var correctSpices:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
correctSpices[meeBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
correctSpices[chickBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
correctSpices[satayBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
correctSpices[laskaBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];
correctSpices[rojakBtn2] = [sp1, sp3];


var firstSpice; //to hold the first spice clicked

var currentDish; //to hold the current dish

currentDish = meeBtn2; //put this on the frame where chicken is the dish

for(var i:int=1; i<= 9;i++){
    this["sp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spiceClick, false, 0, true);
}

function spiceClick(e:Event):void {

    //If the firstSpice variable is null (empty), assign it the click events current target (which is the item you attached the listener to)
    if(firstSpice == null){
        firstSpice = e.currentTarget;
        firstSpice.mouseEnabled = false; //make it so you can't click this one anymore
        return; //exit this function since we want to wait for the second item to be clicked
    }

    //the second item was clicked if we made it this far, check the results

    var ctr:int = 0; //a counter to count how many are correct
    if(correctSpices[currentDish].indexOf(firstSpice) > -1){
        //the first one was correct, add 1 to the counter
        ctr++;
    }

    if(correctSpices[currentDish].indexOf(e.currentTarget) > -1){
        //second one was correct
        ctr++;
    }

    switch(ctr){
        case 2:
            //both items were correct
            output1.text = "Great Job!";

            //go to the next level in 2 seconds
            flash.utils.setTimeout(nextLevel, 2000);
            break; //don't look at any more case statements

        case 1:
            output1.text = "Almost There";
            reset();
            break;

        case 0:
            output1.text = "Try harder...";
            reset();
    }

}
function reset(){
    //reset all the mouse enabled properties so you can click all the buttons again
    for(var i:int=1; i<= 9;i++){
        this["sp" + i].mouseEnabled = true;
    }

    //clear the firstSpice var
    firstSpice = null;
}

function nextLevel(){
    reset();

    nextFrame(); //goto the next frame
}
```

Comment: Hi batman! thank you for your help, really appreciate it! Just one question where i had an error for 1) where flash says an error due to access of possibly undefined property spices. do i have to first create a array of spices (eg: var spices:array = new array(2); ) before entering chickBtn2.spices = [sp1, sp2]; ?

Comment: `chickBtn2.spices = new Array(sp1,sp2);` is exactly the same as doing `checkBtn2.spices = [sp1,sp2];`.  The error is because you've set a dynamic variable the compiler doesn't know exists (since buttons don't have a `spices` property normally).   If you cast the button as an Object it should make the compiler warning go away.   eg.  `Object(checkBtn2).spices= `

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! but it shows me this error.. ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property spices on flash.display.SimpleButton.
 at thespicegame_fla::MainTimeline/frame4()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at thespicegame_fla::MainTimeline/meeBtnfn()

i have uploaded a new file at the link..

Comment: Ah,  it's because SimpleButtons are no dynamic objects (you can't just add a property on the fly)  You can either make the buttons MovieClips (instead of buttons),  or create a dictionary or array to store the correct spices.  I'll update the answer to show how.